# Service Bus multiple listener instances with same subscription not receiving messages

Tags: c#, azure, publish-subscribe, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a **5 node cluster**, each node has a microservice(this is a stateless reliable service) running, which is receiving messages from **Azure Service Bus**.

Since I have created only one my_Subscription(Subscription Name) for my_topic(Topic Name), the microservice instances are receiving messages at random.

I was expecting it to be broadcasted as every instance is subscribed to the Service Bus Topic.

**Now if this the case will I need to create one new subscription per instance, I will need to change the [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-create-first-template) and redeploy it every time whenever I want my services to scale?**

Comment: Isn't this expected behavior considering all your microservice instances are polling just one subscription?

Comment: @GauravMantri  Now if this the case will I need to create one new subscription per instance, I will need to change the ARM template and redeploy it every time whenever I want my services to scale?

Comment: You want same message to be available to all instances. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I want same message to be available to all the instances

Comment: Sounds like you're set-up to use the Competing Consumers pattern - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/competing-consumers

Comment: @PaulSuart : Well I am going to create a sample for this, looks like this gonna help in my case. Will update you.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you want the same message to be processed by multiple instances. Normally we would want the message to be processed only once. Would you mind elaborating on that? Thanks!

Comment: @GauravMantri in my case the need was to update an inMemory cache for all the instances at the same time, so you would need to consume the message in all the instances

Answer (score 1):

If you can make your cluster nodes create own subscription on the fly, as they start up (which should not be too difficult to do). Maybe using something like node's unique ID for the subscription name. Then each node would be receiving its own copy of the message only, achieving your goal. However if your nodes come and go all the time, then you'd need to implement some cleanup mechanism to make sure stale subscriptions don't clog topic's storage.